# I need to convert timestamp to double precision without using EPOCH in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I need to convert timestamp into string or something at one place and convert it back to timestamp at another place.
I tried the following. but i'm getting a slight difference. When i convert it back to timestamp last digit gets missing.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2013-09-27 13:51:02.809501+05:30');
SELECT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE 'epoch' + 1380270062809.5 * INTERVAL '1 millisecond';
```

result is...`"2013-09-27 13:51:02.8095+05:30"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try:

first extract full seconds

`floor(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2013-09-27 13:51:02.809501+05:30'))`

Then add microseconds

`to_char('2013-09-27 13:51:02.809501+05:30'::timestamp, '.US')`,

complete expression:

`SELECT floor(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2013-09-27 13:51:02.809501+05:30')) || to_char('2013-09-27 13:51:02.809501+05:30'::timestamp, '.US')`

source: http://grokbase.com/t/postgresql/pgsql-general/076ercxb4w/precision-of-epoch